# Playframework does not start

Tags: java, scala, playframework

i have been trying to install and create new application on playframework but i keep getting the message "killed"
i tried with version 2.2.x

```
play 2.2.6 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_79), http://www.playframework.com

The new application will be created in /etc/activator/play/survey-app

What is the application name? [survey-app]
> 

Which template do you want to use for this new application? 

  1             - Create a simple Scala application
  2             - Create a simple Java application

> 2
OK, application survey-app is created.

Have fun!

root@Webients:/etc/activator/play# cd survey-app/
root@Webients:/etc/activator/play/survey-app# play run
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
Killed
```

and also with version 2.3.x

```
root@Webients:~# activator new survey-app play-java

Fetching the latest list of templates...

OK, application "survey-app" is being created using the "play-java" template. 

Killed
```

tried to follow all installations recommended on the documentation and searched for a reason on many sites, but can't find a reason.

the machine i'm running is a private VPS with ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, 80GB disk, 128MB Memory, 64MB VSwap

Comment: Something is killing the process before it can do anything. Do you have complete control of the machine you're running it on? Is there something that might be killing off memory intensive processes?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you the default JVM config or your particular Play config is allotting more memory than your system can handle, which would lead to the OS killing your process because of memory starvation.

Take a look at [enter link description here](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/)

> The process to be killed in an out-of-memory situation is selected based on its badness score. The badness score is reflected in /proc//oom_score. This value is determined on the basis that the system loses the minimum amount of work done, recovers a large amount of memory, doesn't kill any innocent process eating tons of memory, and kills the minimum number of processes (if possible limited to one). The badness score is computed using the original memory size of the process, its CPU time (utime + stime), the run time (uptime - start time) and its oom_adj value. The more memory the process uses, the higher the score. The longer a process is alive in the system, the smaller the score.

Since your process is killed almost immediately, i assume it starts with a high *Bad* score.